# disable wpa_supplicant service

Tags: networkmanager, services, void-linux

I'am new user in base-void-linux and I need to enable NetworkManager.

For that I need to disable `dhcpcd` and `wpa_supplicant` services. I need help for how to disable `wpa_supplicant` service.

Comment: Your distribution has installation documentation that I just looked at.  Have you read it or attempted to use it? Specifically [NetworkManager](https://docs.voidlinux.org/config/network/networkmanager.html)

Answer (score 0):

Under runit, you should remove the symlink:

```
# rm -f /var/service/wpa_supplicant.service
# rm -f /var/service/dhcpcd.service
```

[Void docs: disabling service](https://docs.voidlinux.org/config/services/index.html#disabling-services)